# Pre-Made ActiveRecord to Optimize Performance / Save Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Essentially each time a visitor reaches the application, the controller performs a database query to check what are the most relevant items to show.

Although the items shown vary with time, they are not personally selected for each user.

This means that instead of being calculated each time a visitor comes, it would be better to be system performing a single query every like 10 minutes and store it, to apply on each visit.

What is the best way to apply this idea? I was thinking on cronjobs and maybe store on redis but IDK, some help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe use [fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) with a [cache store](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this.  One way that I've used in the past with success is to have a table in your database that represents the most relevant items and then have a cron job that updates that table.

Fragment caching like @wesley6j recommended isn't a bad way to go either and you can combine the 2 techniques as well if you want.

If you want more detailed suggestions, you can provide some more details about what you are trying to achieve.